# pass a parameter into named query

Tags: html, netbeans, parameter-passing, jsp-tags, named-query

I have the following query in my model(Supplier) class :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Supplier.findSupplierKeyId", query = "SELECT s FROM Supplier s WHERE s.supplierid LIKE (':supplieridkey%')")
```

I have following function in my Controller(SupplierSerivce) class:

```
public List<Supplier> findSupplierKeyId(String supplierkeyid){
    List<Supplier> supplierList = mgr.createNamedQuery("Supplier.findSupplierKeyId").setParameter("supplieridkey", supplierkeyid).getResultList();
    return supplierList;
}
```

I want to get in a html textfield :

```
<form action="SearchSupplierIdKey.jsp" method="POST">
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" name="supIdKey"/>
                            <input type="submit" value="Search" name="button"/>
                        </div>
</form>
```

then get parameter from the textfield and pass it into supService.findSupplierKeyId through servlet:
public class SearchSupplierIdKey extends HttpServlet {

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        SupplierService supService = new SupplierService(em);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String supId = (String) session.getAttribute("supId");
        String button = (String) session.getAttribute("button");

        List<Supplier> supplierListResult = supService.findSupplierKeyId(supId);
        session.setAttribute("supplierListResult", supplierListResult);
        if (button.equals("Search")) {
            response.sendRedirect("ViewSupplierByIdKey.jsp");
        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddSupplier.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Then show the result in ViewSupplierByIdKey.jsp :

```
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="model.Supplier"%>

<!-- retrieve session object, itemList -->
<%
  List<Supplier> supplierListResult = (List)session.getAttribute("supplierListResult");
%>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Supplier Search Result</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border:solid; width: 1000px">
        <tr style="border:solid">
            <td style="border:solid ">
                <h3 style="text-align: center">ABC Health Supplement Shop System</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border: solid">
            <td style="border: solid">
                <center><h1><i><b><font face="Segoe Script" color="#FF0000">Supplier Search Result(By ID Key)</font></b></i></h1></center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border:solid">
            <td style="border:solid">
                <center><div>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Supplier ID</th>
                            <th>Supplier Name</th>
                            <th>Manufacturer</th>
                            <th>Contact Num</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                        </tr>
                        <% for (Supplier supplier: supplierListResult){ %>
                            <tr>
                                <td><%= supplier.getSupplierid() %></td>
                                <td><%= supplier.getSuppliername()%> </td>
                                <td><%= supplier.getManufacturer()%> </td>
                                <td><%= supplier.getContactnum()%> </td>
                                <td><%= supplier.getAddress()%> </td>
                            </tr>
                        <% } %>
                    </table>
                    <br><br>
                    <p><a href="index.html">Back to Menu page</a></p>

                </div>
                </center>
            </td>

        </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

but i dont knw why i cant proceed to ViewSupplierByIdKey.jsp, it stuck at the controller class
(SearchSupplierIdKey.java). Please Help :( :(

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I notice is the request parameter is retrieved using the name `supId`:

```
String supId = (String) session.getAttribute("supId");
```

but specified as `supIdKey` in the HTML:

```
 <input type="text" name="supIdKey"/>
```

The `name` attribute used on the `input` should match the key being used to retrieve the attribute.